# Do actors get paid more to do their own stunts?

Tags: film-industry, stunts

There are several actors who are [known for doing their own stunts](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls054699485/). Generally speaking, is it an industry convention to pay actors "bonuses" for performing their own stunts?

Comment: Kinda doubt that. If anything it is an extra cost, due to the higher insurance: because if the actor get seriously hurt, it shuts down the whole production.

Comment: Could be. It depends on production and actor's interests. But as @BCdotWEB pointed out, actors will not get more payments. If actor requested that he/she'll be better suited for the stunts, and willing to take the risks, producers may pay original actor rather than stunt actor. But as above, the risk is higher. actor may get hurt and may cause entire movie/show to wrap up or halt

Comment: @BCdotWEB the only possible exception I can think of would be if the added insurance costs get offset from additional profits associated with main characters performing their own stunts.  That said; I doubt actors performing their own stunts really gets more people to see it or buy related products.

Comment: @JMac It can be extra promo (e.g. Tom Cruise insisting on doing almost all of his stunts in the Mission: Impossible movies is footage that often ends up as "news"), but it's hard to measure such effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, actors do not get paid extra to do their own stunts.  Some actors enjoy the challenge of doing the stuntwork, while others feel it adds a level of believability to a movie if the actor's face can be seen clearly while a stunt is performed.  This means that tricks used to hide stunt doubles (How many times have you seen an actor fall or roll down an embankment and they always end up with their arm covering their face?) can be forgone.  Not to pick on one actor, but Tom Cruise willing to do his own stunts is probably pretty important to his movies, because there probably aren't a lot of people out there doing stunts who have a similar build and height.

Comment: Has Jackie Chan ever used a stunt double?

Comment: Does Tom Cruise do all of his stunts in all of his movies?   That would be cool if you could edit examples of his movies into your answer  :)

Comment: I know Cruise does a lot of them, there's plenty of youtube videos showing his stuntwork.  As for Jackie Chan, I'm not positive if he's ever used a stunt double.  He's been injured during shoots and has required hospital visits, I'd imagine some of those stunts may have needed a stunt double just to move production along but I can't say with 100% certainty.

Comment: @rtaft: Yes. But he only acknowledges it for complex stunts or ones requiring specialized skills. https://www.theguardian.com/film/2003/jan/22/news1